# Tensor(..., shape=(), dtype=int64) must be from the same graph as Tensor(..., shape=(), dtype=resource) Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras to run a Conv2D net to read a set a folder that contain the hand-gesture images from [20bn Jester](https://20bn.com/products/datasets)
I know a Conv2D probably won't work, but I want to get something that I've used before to run correctly before altering too much code. 
However, I keep running into

```
ValueError: Tensor("training/Adamax/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Adamax/iterations:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).
```

and don't understand enough to fix it.
I've tried other answers about resetting the graph

```
import keras 
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

or

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

but neither, or both, work.

My image file structure is something like:
`../images/train/[Gesture]/[Sample]/Image001.png`

which is a level deeper than I've used before, but the flow_from_directory correctly outputs the image and class count, for training and validation sets

```
Found 3456570 images belonging to 27 classes.
Found 532578 images belonging to 27 classes.
```

Conda list:

```
...
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0  
cudnn                     7.6.4                cuda10.0_0 
...
keras                     2.3.1                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-base                2.3.1                    py37_0  
keras-gpu                 2.3.1                         0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
...
tensorboard               1.14.0           py37hf484d3e_0  
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py37h4491b45_0  
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py37h8d69cac_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import glob
import shutil
import pickle
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import tensorflow as tf

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
tf.reset_default_graph()

# read in the training and validation labels
trainPairs = np.genfromtxt('/home/me/Videos/sign_language/jester-v1-train.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=0, dtype=[('class', 'S12'),('sign','S50')])
trainLabels = [v for k,v in trainPairs]

validPairs = np.genfromtxt('/home/me/Videos/sign_language/jester-v1-validation.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=0, dtype=[('class', 'S12'),('sign','S50')])
validLabels = [v for k,v in validPairs]

def copyDirectory(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    # Directories are the same
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
    # Any error saying that the directory doesn't exist
    except OSError as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

source = '/media/me/other/20bn-jester-v1/'
dest = '/media/me/other/jester/validation/'

# counter = 0
# for k,v in validPairs:
#     counter = counter + 1
#     source_folder = source + k.decode("utf-8")
#     dest_folder = dest + v.decode("utf-8") + "/" + k.decode("utf-8")

#     if counter%100 == 0:        
#         print(k)
#         print(v)
#         print(counter)
#         print(source_folder)
#         print(dest_folder)

#     if os.path.isdir(source_folder):
#         if os.path.isdir(dest + v.decode("utf-8")):
#             copyDirectory(source_folder, dest_folder)        

#     if counter%1000 == 0:
#         print(counter)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/train/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)
valid_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/validation/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=64)
# test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/test/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)

seed = 21
epochs = 5
optimizer = 'Adamax'

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = Sequential()

model = Sequential()


#model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), padding='same'))
#TODO is this the right shape??
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(256, 256, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(3,32,32), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(128, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#TODO make this a variable
model.add(Dense(27))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

### I think everything up to here is ok???

global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)

print(model.summary())

np.random.seed(seed)

image_batch_train, label_batch_train = next(iter(train_it))
print("Image batch shape: ", image_batch_train.shape)
print("Label batch shape: ", label_batch_train.shape)
dataset_labels = sorted(train_it.class_indices.items(), key=lambda pair:pair[1])
dataset_labels = np.array([key.title() for key, value in dataset_labels])

print(dataset_labels)

from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()

import keras 
keras.backend.clear_session()

tf.reset_default_graph()
model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)

#scores = model.evaluate(test_it, steps=24, verbose=0)
#print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

Edit 1: Added Logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-09b1bdd2e389>", line 152, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 42, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 599, in get_updates
    self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1268, in update_add
    return tf_state_ops.assign_add(x, increment)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 195, in assign_add
    return ref.assign_add(value)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py", line 1108, in assign_add
    name=name)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 68, in assign_add_variable_op
    "AssignAddVariableOp", resource=resource, value=value, name=name)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 366, in _apply_op_helper
    g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6135, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6071, in _assert_same_graph
    (item, original_item))

ValueError: Tensor("training/Adamax/Const:0", shape=(), dtype=int64) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Adamax/iterations:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).
```

Comment: What line exactly is giving you the exception? Can you add the stack trace to the question?

Comment: I've added the log, was that what you were referring to? 
Is there a way to add further debugging which would be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are resetting your default graph before training the model:

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()  # <-- remove this line
model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)
```

The problem is as follows. You reset first the default graph at the beginning, which, unless your actual script has more code before that, doesn't really make any difference, since the default graph is empty at that point. Then you make your model, and it creates operations on the new default graph. That new default graph is the one you get later with:

```py
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

The problem is later, after clearing the Keras session twice (which doesn't have any effect either), you reset the default graph again. When you call `fit`, the training process starts, and some new graph objects of the Keras model are created. Since your default graph has changed it (because you reset it), those new objects are created in a different graph from the rest of objects, which causes the error. I think you still could reset the graph and have it work if you use the former default graph as default during the training:

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
with graph.as_default():  # Use former default graph as default
    model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)
```

I'm not completely sure if the Keras default session will always work (since it might have been created for the new default graph), but I think it should... In any case, if you for whatever reason you want to have your Keras model isolated in its own graph, instead of resetting the graph you can do it as follows:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:  # Make a new graph and use it as default
    # Make dataset
    # Make model
    # Train
```