# ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient - Not using Custom

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As per the title, I get this common error when trying to use Keras to do some Image Classification training. Unlike nearly all of the other examples, I am *not* trying to customise anything and simply using bog-standard keras functionality!
Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122371/valueerror-an-operation-has-none-for-gradient-without-custom-layer-or-loss-f), who asks a similar question, but doesn't appear to have followed up.

I previously had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543081/tensor-shape-dtype-int64-must-be-from-the-same-graph-as-tensor-sh) with this same project, but after having upgraded cudnn, and cudatoolkit (and relevant NVidia backends) I get this new error.

Conda List:

```
# packages in environment at /home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu  
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py37_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py37_0  
astor                     0.8.0                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.3                    py37_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.4.4                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.4                      py_0  
blinker                   1.4                      py37_0  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
c-ares                    1.15.0            h7b6447c_1001  
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0  
cachetools                3.1.1                      py_0  
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2020.4.5.1               py37_0  
cffi                      1.14.0           py37h2e261b9_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.1.1                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.4.0                      py_0  
cryptography              2.8              py37h1ba5d50_0  
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0  
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0  
cupti                     10.1.168                      0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20181111                   py_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                he6710b0_0  
ffmpeg                    4.0                  hcdf2ecd_0  
flake8                    3.7.9                    py37_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freeglut                  3.0.0                hf484d3e_5  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_1  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_0  
gast                      0.2.2                    py37_0  
glib                      2.63.1               h5a9c865_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
google-auth               1.13.1                     py_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2  
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0  
graphite2                 1.3.13               h23475e2_0  
grpcio                    1.27.2           py37hf8bcb03_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
h5py                      2.8.0           py37h3010b51_1003    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3  
idna                      2.9                        py_1  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib_metadata        1.5.0                    py37_0  
intel-openmp              2020.0                      166  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0  
ipykernel                 5.1.4            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
jasper                    2.0.14               h07fcdf6_1  
jedi                      0.15.2                   py37_0  
jeepney                   0.4.3                      py_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py37_0  
keras                     2.3.1                         0  
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-base                2.3.1                    py37_0  
keras-gpu                 2.3.1                         0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
keyring                   21.1.1                   py37_2  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37hfd86e86_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py37h7b6447c_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libglu                    9.0.0                hf484d3e_1  
libopencv                 3.4.2                hb342d67_1  
libopus                   1.3.1                h7b6447c_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libprotobuf               3.11.4               hd408876_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                he6710b0_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_0  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h439df22_0  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hea5a465_1  
markdown                  3.1.1                    py37_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.1.3                    py37_0  
matplotlib-base           3.1.3            py37hef1b27d_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl                       2020.0                      166  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py37ha843d7b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37hd6b4f25_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0  
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h4f9e942_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hde5b4d6_1  
numpydoc                  0.9.2                      py_0  
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
opencv                    3.4.2            py37h6fd60c2_1  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h7b6447c_0  
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0  
packaging                 20.3                       py_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.2                      py_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
pcre                      8.43                 he6710b0_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.0.0            py37hb39fc2d_0  
pip                       20.0.2                   py37_1  
pixman                    0.38.0               h7b6447c_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.4                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.4                         0  
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37he6710b0_0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py37hb342d67_1  
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0  
pydocstyle                4.0.1                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0  
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py37_0  
pylint                    2.5.0                    py37_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.7           hcf32534_0_cpython  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_0  
python-language-server    0.31.10                  py37_0  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pyxdg                     0.26                       py_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h7b6447c_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py37he6710b0_0  
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.7.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.7.3                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
requests                  2.23.0                   py37_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0  
rope                      0.16.0                     py_0  
rsa                       4.0                        py_0  
rtree                     0.9.4                    py37_1  
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h0b6359f_0  
secretstorage             3.1.2                    py37_0  
setuptools                46.1.3                   py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.14.0                   py37_0  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
sphinx                    3.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0  
spyder                    4.1.2                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            1.9.0                    py37_0  
sqlite                    3.31.1               h62c20be_1  
tensorboard               2.1.0                     py3_0  
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0  
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py37h6c5654b_0  
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0  
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                h0d30ee6_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py37_1  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
toml                      0.10.0           py37h28b3542_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h7b6447c_1  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
ujson                     1.35             py37h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.25.8                   py37_0  
watchdog                  0.10.2                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.9                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0  
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37h7b6447c_1  
wurlitzer                 2.0.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
yapf                      0.28.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.1                he6710b0_3  
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Code

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import pickle
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import tensorflow as tf

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"

# read in the training and validation labels
trainPairs = np.genfromtxt('/home/me/Videos/sign_language/jester-v1-train.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=0, dtype=[('class', 'S12'),('sign','S50')])
trainLabels = [v for k,v in trainPairs]

validPairs = np.genfromtxt('/home/me/Videos/sign_language/jester-v1-validation.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=0, dtype=[('class', 'S12'),('sign','S50')])
validLabels = [v for k,v in validPairs]

def copyDirectory(src, dest):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dest)
    # Directories are the same
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
    # Any error saying that the directory doesn't exist
    except OSError as e:
        print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

source = '/media/me/other/20bn-jester-v1/'
dest = '/media/me/other/jester/validation/'

# counter = 0
# for k,v in validPairs:
#     counter = counter + 1
#     source_folder = source + k.decode("utf-8")
#     dest_folder = dest + v.decode("utf-8") + "/" + k.decode("utf-8")

#     if counter%100 == 0:        
#         print(k)
#         print(v)
#         print(counter)
#         print(source_folder)
#         print(dest_folder)

#     if os.path.isdir(source_folder):
#         if os.path.isdir(dest + v.decode("utf-8")):
#             copyDirectory(source_folder, dest_folder)        

#     if counter%1000 == 0:
#         print(counter)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/train/', 
                                       class_mode='categorical', 
                                       batch_size=16
)
valid_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/validation/', class_mode='categorical', batch_size=16)
# test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('/media/me/other/jester/test/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)

seed = 21
epochs = 5
optimizer = 'Adamax'

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = Sequential()

#model = Sequential()


#model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), padding='same'))
#TODO is this the right shape??
model.add(Conv2D(32,(16,16), strides=(8,8), input_shape=(256, 256, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(3,16,16), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
#model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same'))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(Dense(256, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(128, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

#TODO make this a variable
model.add(Dense(27))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])


for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)

print(model.summary())

np.random.seed(seed)

image_batch_train, label_batch_train = next(iter(train_it))
print("Image batch shape: ", image_batch_train.shape)
print("Label batch shape: ", label_batch_train.shape)
dataset_labels = sorted(train_it.class_indices.items(), key=lambda pair:pair[1])
dataset_labels = np.array([key.title() for key, value in dataset_labels])

print(dataset_labels)

from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()

import keras 
keras.backend.clear_session()


model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)
```

Log

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()

import keras 
keras.backend.clear_session()


model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-ba2ec4f0a2a8>", line 8, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_it, steps_per_epoch=16, validation_data=valid_it, validation_steps=8)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 42, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 598, in get_updates
    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)

  File "/home/me/Programs/anaconda3/envs/hand-gesture/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 93, in get_gradients
    raise ValueError('An operation has `None` for gradient. '

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

Edit 1:
Following Matias' recommendation and removing the

```
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()

import keras 
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

allows me to run one epoch, but now I get

```
Epoch 1/1
16/16 [==============================] - 6s 370ms/step - loss: 4.0208 - accuracy: 0.0391 - val_loss: 7.3795 - val_accuracy: 0.0469
Out[3]: <keras.callbacks.callbacks.History at 0x7f817e63c2d0>
```

Edit 2:
As Matias pointed out, my code was only set to run 1 epoch. So, removing the `clear_session()` worked to fix my problem.

Comment: Why are you calling K.clear_session() before calling fit_generator?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I was trying to fix another problem that I was having (which may have "resolved itself" by upgrading versions).

Removing that line does fix that error, and I can run one epoch. Once that finishes though I now get another message. Updated question.

Comment: I do not see any problem now. What is the new question?

Comment: It only runs one epoch, then stops, which isn't expected behaviour, as I'm expecting 5 epochs.

Comment: You are not setting epochs to 5, it seems epochs is set to one, as it says Epochs 1/1

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  *sigh* you are correct. 
If you want to put "remove K.clear_session()" as an answer, I'll accept it because that solved my initial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are clearing the session before training the model, doing this would make no sense, because clearing the session cleans the model structures in memory, so there would be no model representation in the TensorFlow side, making training fail.

So do not juse `K.clear_session()` in this case. It does not seem to be needed.